# When are spring constant of parallel springs equal

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, spring

I know that in a parallel spring system the equivalent spring constant $k$ is the sum of the spring constants $k_1$ and $k_2$ of the individual springs:
$$k=k_1+k_2$$

As discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/695083/two-springs-in-parallel), if the spring constants are different, then the extensions will be different.

To be specific, take the context where a mass is hung from two massless springs. The springs are attached to a horizontal support. Hence, the force on the mass is gravity.
(To ensure that we work only in two dimensions, suppose that the springs and mass are next to a frictionless wall).

Hence, the mass cannot twist. But it could be that one side of the mass is pulled down more than the other (by gravity).

What information is required to conclude that the spring constants are equal($k_1=k_2$).

1. Attachment points are symmetrical.
2. Extension of both springs is same.

Will some combination of the above two work? Or is something else required?

Comment: Can the connections rotate?

Comment: Have added context regarding rotation.

Comment: Thank you. Hooke's Law for springs is $F_i=k_ix_i$ for spring $i$, or $k_i=F_i/x_i$. Your condition #2 states that $x_1=x_2$. With no additional factors, symmetry from condition #1 indicates that $F_1=F_2$. This implies $k_1=k_2$. Alternatively, $F_1$ and $x_1$ could each be scaled by the same factor relative to $F_2$ and $x_2$, and this would also give $k_1=k_2$. It's not clear what you're ultimately trying to do/show.

Comment: Please don't ask questions in a roundabout way, referring to mystery images ("as shown above"). It wastes everyone's time to have to tease out details that you've chosen not to present.

Comment: Two massless springs, of spring constants k_1 and k_2, are hung from a horizontal support. A block of weight 12N is suspended from the pair of springs. When the block is in equilibrium, each spring is stretched an additional 24 cm. Thus, the equivalent spring constant of the two-spring system is 12 N / 24 cm =0.5 N/cm. Which of the following statements is correct about k1 and k2?
k_1=k_2=0.25 N/cm
1/k_1+1/k_2=1/(0.5 N/cm)
k_1–k_2=0.5N/cm
k_1+k_2=0.5 N/cm

Comment: Sorry. All the information related to the question is in the text. The diagram just shows two springs from a horizontal support to which a mass is attached.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the constants equation is if the extensions are the same. For your question, the constraint would be static equilibrium. Assuming your springs are equally spaced about the mass center, it is the force that will be equal. If not you must do a static equilibrium analysis.

There is no single constant, since the two displacements are different. The object displaces and rotates. However, you can resolve this into a hypothetical single spring and single torsion spring pair. The effective spring will not necessarily be in  the center. It is not clear to me that this is helpful, I would just treat it as two springs with two displacements.